# Issue with topic level policy setup in apache-pulsar

Tags: apache-pulsar

I have changed the topic level policy in the broker.conf and standalone.conf file

```
systemTopicEnabled=true
topicLevelPoliciesEnabled=true
```

When i execute the below command it's failing due to policy not set message.

```
bin/pulsar-admin topics set-replication-clusters --clusters east-region-pulsar,pulsar-west my-tenant/my-namespace/my-topic
```

> Failed to perform http post request: javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
> Topic level policies is disabled, to enable the topic level policy and retry.
>
> Reason: Topic level policies is disabled, to enable the topic level policy and retry.

How to resolve the issue?